# How to make wordpress folder (/wordpress) redirect to /?

Tags: redirect

I have my website setup with Wordpress in its own folder. The URL website.com/wordpress is currently a 404 (which makes sense since the page doesn't exist), but I want it to redirect back to the root.

I've tried using the Redirection plugin to setup the redirect, but it is still a 404.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is actually an **`.htaccess`** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 1):

Wait, scratch my comment above. :/

1. Go to **Admin** -> **Settings** -> **General**
2. Ensure **WordPress URL** remains the same (e.g. `example.com/wordpress`)
3. Change **Site URL** to remove the subdirectory (e.g. `example.com`)
4. For good measure, go to **Admin** -> **Settings** -> **Permalinks** to flush your rewrite rules

That *should* be all you need.